# How can you securely store a JWT token with Auth0 and React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, authorization, auth0

I'm trying to find a relatively secure way to store JWT-tokens in my distributed web app with a React front-end, using Auth0. I'm currently using local storage, however this is vulnerable to XSS and CSRF. Session storage is not an option, since a re-login is necessary after the site is closed. I think 2 alternatives remain:

- **In-memory storage**

As far as I know, this would be the most secure option and recommended by Auth0. However, I cannot call the `getAccessTokenSilently` hook everywhere.

Currently this is my code for API request:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null


export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8080/`,
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
    timeout: 2000
});
```

When refactoring this code to use `getAccessTokenSilently` to achieve in-memory storage, I get the following error:
`Line 3:34: React Hook "useAuth0" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useAuth0} from "@auth0/auth0-react";
const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0();

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8080/`,
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessTokenSilently}`},
    timeout: 2000
});
```

Is there any way to fix this? For GET-request I'm using a custom hook, but since a hook is always called imminently / at top level I cannot use it for POST-request (like adding a product).

- **HTTP only cookie**

Since this is not recommended by Auth0 it would not be a preference, but an alternative if possible.

**Auth0 SPA settings**:
[image]

**Auth0 API settings**:
[image]

Thanks for your suggestions